# ASP.Net GridView 5000 Records

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

If a procedure returns 5000 (Five Thousand) rows and I want bind it with a `Asp.net Grid View`. Neither it won’t be good approach to call all the rows and bind it with grid and then on grid view Pageindex see all the data or this approach to strike the DB at each `Pageindex` change. So can anybody give me good answer.

Comment: Did you try server side paging??

Comment: Return only a subset of records, here is a full tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb445504.aspx

Comment: Tim I think you approach is better I'll

Answer (score 3):

Normally your GridView is only presentation. So you only have to query the correct page to display in the GridView. If you go the the next page you query the db for the next page.

This article will give you directions on how to do this with a datasource:

[MSDN - Tutorial 25: Efficiently Paging Through Large Amounts of Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb445504.aspx)

[Efficient Server Side Paging with the ASP.NET GridView Control](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=267)

Answer (score -1):

```
Session["dt"] = DataTable; //after you get table from procedure, assign it to session
```

Then in pageload, every time bind grid view to datatable saved in session, you call it from DB just first time

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView.DataSource = Session["dt"];
            GridView.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: It might be worth to point out that storing large objects in the session is not one of the best practices.

Comment: I wonder if you ever tried storing such a large ammount of data in session.

Comment: If your result-set takes up 500K and you have 100 users using the application you are looking at 50MB of memory being chewed up on the server with just this practice alone...

Comment: table with 5000 rows is not large amount of data.

Comment: aleafonso i think your are right.. it won't be good approach to store very huge amount of data... lets say its more than 60K rows then this approach will fail..